# How to use React JSX inside Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I get an error of unexpected token right where jsx begins. How to use JSX inside directive controller? Do I need to change attribute of a file somehow?

```
controller: function($scope, $t){

            var Table = FixedDataTable.Table;
            var Column = FixedDataTable.Column;



            React.render(
                <Table
                    rowHeight={50}
                    rowGetter={rowGetter}
                    rowsCount={rows.length}
                    width={5000}
                    height={5000}
                    headerHeight={50}>
                    <Column
                        label="Col 1"
                        width={3000}
                        dataKey={0}
                        />
                    <Column
                        label="Col 2"
                        width={500}
                        dataKey={1}
                        />

                </Table>,

                document.getElementById('table')
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't define the render function inside the js file it should be in a jsx file.
You can't just start adding code from other language into your js files i recommend you to read this article [**Facebook's React vs AngularJS: A Closer Look**](http://www.quora.com/Pete-Hunt/Posts/Facebooks-React-vs-AngularJS-A-Closer-Look)

We are using [`bower-react`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-bower) to our project. And the code should look something similar to this

Your directive:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  var tableComponent = React.renderComponent(
          react.table({
            myParam: myValue
          }),
          element.find('#table').get(0)
        );
}
```

As you can see Angular is only calling the `renderComponent` function and sending parameters or callbacks. If the model changes you should call `tableComponent .setState(newData)` from Angular as well

Your jsx file:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
(function(react) {
  'use strict';
    // Vars
    // Functions
    react.table = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return(
           <Table 
                  myParam={this.props.myParam}
                  rowHeight={50}
                  rowGetter={rowGetter}
                  rowsCount={rows.length}
                  width={5000}
                  height={5000}
                  headerHeight={50}>
                  <Column
                      label="Col 1"
                      width={3000}
                      dataKey={0}
                      />
                  <Column
                      label="Col 2"
                      width={500}
                      dataKey={1}
                      />
                </Table>
        );
      }
    });
}(react));
```